# Minitest/Rails: DateTime.now versus DateTime.current in travel_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, minitest

Is the following behavior of the **travel_to** test helper a bug or a feature? Either way, why is it happening this way and should **DateTime.now** be avoided altogether in Rails code?

Using **ruby (2.3.1)**, **rails (4.2.6)** and **minitest (5.9.0)**:

```
  test 'traveling to 1900 (Time)' do
    travel_to Time.new(1916, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0) do
      puts Time.current
      puts Time.now
      puts DateTime.current
      puts DateTime.now
      puts Time.zone.now
      puts Time.zone.today
    end
  end
```

=>

```
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01T07:00:00+00:00
2016-08-18T14:29:20+02:00
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01
```

Similarly,

```
  test 'traveling to 1900 (DateTime)' do
    travel_to DateTime.new(1916, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0) do
      puts Time.current
      puts Time.now
      puts DateTime.current
      puts DateTime.now
      puts Time.zone.now
      puts Time.zone.today
    end
  end
```

=>

```
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01T07:00:00+00:00
2016-08-18T14:29:24+02:00
1916-01-01 07:00:00 UTC
1916-01-01
```

Comment: Have you tried the ``timecop`` gem? Maybe ``travel_to`` is not complete yet.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and use `Time.zone.now` and `Time.zone.today`?

IMHO this is the API which should be used in Rails projects. Also see http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/